# How would you use len() to find amount of items in a dictionary of lists in JSON?

Tags: python, json, database, dictionary

## Take a look at this example:

```
 "guy": {
        "coins": 0,
        "tickets": 0,
        "family": "none",
        "friends": 0,
        "enemies": 0,
        "inventory": {
            "boxes": 0,
            "papers": 0
        },
        "fridge": {
            "fruits": ["apple","apple", "banana", "avocado"],
            "vegetables": ["cucumber", "cucumber", "cucumber", "carrot"],
            "meat": ["minced", "raw", "cooked"],
            "drinks": ["water", "water", "orange_juice"],
            "other_stuff": ["ice_cubes"],
        },
    }
```

This is an absolutely random and wild example, but I want you to focus on the "fridge" dictionary. If I wanted to know how many items are in "guy"'s fridge, how would I do so? I tried this:

```
with open("guys.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(len(data["guy"]["fridge"]))
```

and the output (which was expected) was:

```
5
```

That makes sense because there is 5 TYPES of items in the fridge, but I want to know how many ITEMS there are, not TYPES! I know, I know, we could do this:

```
len(data["guy"]["fridge"]["fruits"]) + len(data["guy"]["fridge"]["vegetables"]) + len(data["guy"]["meat"]) + len(data["guy"]["fridge"]["drinks"]) + len(data["guy"]["fridge"]["other_Stuff"])
```

But this is definitely not the best method if you have LOTS of food types in your fridge...

## How would you do this differently with much less lines of code?

Can you use a 'for' loop on this? How else can you find out how many items are in my fridge (in this example)? I have a "fridge" with 30+ types of items, I won't type all that code if there is an easier alternative!
Thanks -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the `len` function to each element of the values, and then add it up!

```py
sum(map(len, data["guy"]["fridge"].values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` which basically flattens iterables of iterables, in your case the values of the fridge dictionary.

```
import itertools

len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data["guy"]["fridge"].values())))

# result:
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sum the lengths in a for-loop:

```py
sum([len(i) for i in data["guy"]["fridge"].values()])
```

ItzTheDodo.

Comment: The `[]` are superfluous and make this operation unnecessarily inefficient…